# Docker mounting volume. Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, permissions, docker-volume

I have a problem with creating new files in mounted docker volume.

Firstly after installation docker i added my user to docker group.

```
sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

Created as my $USER folder:

```
mkdir -p /srv/redis
```

And starting container:

```
docker run -d -v /srv/redis:/data --name myredis redis
```

when i want to create file in /srv/redis as a user which created container I have a problem with access.

```
mkdir /srv/redis/redisTest
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/srv/redis/redisTest’: Permission denied
```

I tried to search in other threads but i didn't find appropriate solution.

Comment: what is the user you are trying to run `mkdir redisTest`? and to what groups it belongs?

Comment: User which created redis container, which is in group docker @DevDio i edited the mkdir path

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The question title does not reflect the real problem in my opinion.

```
mkdir /srv/redis/redisTest
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/srv/redis/redisTest’: Permission denied
```

This problem occurs very likely because when you run:

```
docker run -d -v /srv/redis:/data --name myredis redis
```

the directory `/srv/redis` ownership changes to `root`. You can check that by

```
ls -lah /srv/redis
```

This is normal consequence of mounting external directory to `docker`. To regain access you have to run

```
sudo chown -R $USER /srv/redis
```

Comment: Seems like chown works, but is it secure to chown directory which redis container save his files ?

Comment: @moviss To answer your question. When you run docker again on the volume, some files may get re-chowned to root again, or the application therein (i.e. redis) may even fail because of wrong ownership. So it is a dilemma that I don't have a perfect answer. But you may want to study this docker setup on github that I contributed to, where you can run docker with none-root user. It may give you  some ideas: https://github.com/broadinstitute/viral-ngs-deploy/blob/master/docker. Take close look at Dockerfile and env_wrapper.sh where I used `gosu`

Answer (score 2):

This could also be related (as I just found out) to having SELinux activated. [This answer on the DevOps Stack Exchange worked for me](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/11277):

> The solution is to simply append a :z to the [docker] run volume argument so that this:
>
> `docker run -v /host/foobar:/src_dir /bin/bash`
>
> becomes this:
>
> `docker run -it -v /host/foobar:/src_dir:z /bin/bash`

Answer (score 1):

I think `/srv/redis/redisTest` directory is created by user inside `redis` container, so it belong to `redis` container user.

Have you already check using `ls -l` to see that `/srv/redis/redisTest` directory belong to `$USER`?

Comment: I want to create directory outside of container :P

Comment: yea .. but when you mount it that way, the directory under /srv/redis/ would be created automatically by the container. . like @biocyberman said. .its very likely that directory belong to root inside redis container.. even if you created it manually